# Share common models between two Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an E-commerce application and also working on its admin website. These two applications have the same business domain and there are a few models from the e-commerce application that I need in the admin app.

I have found a few solutions online for sharing models although I am not clear which is better and how should I implement it.

Solutions I found:

1. [Create a rake task to copy the models from the e-commerce app to the admin app](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/10/14/rails-tricks-sharing-the-model)
2. [Create a third ruby module and put the models in there and pull the models from the app directory into this newly created lib and require it inside the app](http://blog.8thlight.com/jim-suchy/2007/02/20/sharing-a-database-among-multiple-rails-applications.html)
3. Auto loading the models from the e-commerce app to admin ruby search

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/../e-commerce-app/app/models/)
   ```

I think the second solution is the right way to do it though I am unsure of how to implement it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of these.

How about creating a shared gem and put that on your private git repo? With Rails, you can provide the same mechanism for autoloading the models within the application itself by packaging the gem as a rails_engine

See [example](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/rails-autoloading-for-your-gem/)

At the end require it within Gemfile

```
gem 'my_gem_name', git: 'http:my_git_repo.com/my_gem_name'
```

A more advance solution would be creating a REST service for the desired data in the e-commerce app and consume it in the admin app. Especially for Users (and authentication), it would even make sense to extract it to a separate app and provide a UserAuthentication Service.

Comment: It's a hard problem, actually. Normally, admin interface doesn't need the "full" models (with all of the validations, email hooks and whatnot). Bundling the models in a shared gem may create dependencies for admin app, which wouldn't be needed if it used just a simplified copy.

Comment: You don't have to package all the models into gem. Only the common ones. And you're also touching an interesting point. The fact that you have to access same data on different apps does not necessarily mean that it should be done by exact same models. Sometimes there is just another business logic for same data access and it's better to extract behaviour into separate classes in order not to blow up a model

Comment: Now the e-commerce site has User model which I use for devise authentication. I am providing user statistics to the admin so I would need access to that User model in the admin application. So can I have the User model in a gem and also have devise authentication on it for the E-commerce application ??

Comment: Actually you can. You'll have to include devise and a proper config in both apps. If you don't need the devise stuff for user in the admin app. You could extract the common model functionality into a ruby module and only share that instead of the whole model. `class User < ActiveRecord::Base; include UserBase; end`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is by creating a 'Mountable' gem using the command line:

```
rails plugin new e_commerce_app_core --mountable
```

This will set up your rails engine so all you need to do is move your model(s) from your app to `e_commerce_app_core/app/models/`.

I include the gem like this:

```
gem 'e_commerce_app_core_core', git: 'https://github.com/my_repo/e_commerce_app_core_core.git'
```

Then I run:

```
bundle config local.e_commerce_app_core_core ../e_commerce_app_core_core
```

This command attached your local directory to your build instead of using the external repo. That way I can work with the gem locally and push it up to github when I'm ready.

I also moved my user controller that contained log in logic but to get my user routes to work I changed my `config/routes.rb` from:

```
ECommerceAppCore::Engine.routes.draw do
  ...
end
```

to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
end
```

I moved my migrations to my gem by adding this to my `application.rb`:

```
config.paths['db/migrate'] = ECommerceAppCore::Engine.paths['db/migrate'].existent
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Git-subtree.

Git Subtree is used for sharing code between rails applications

Please have look at- http://igor-alexandrov.github.io/blog/2013/03/28/using-git-subtree-to-share-code-between-rails-applications/

I think this will help you.